# Expected number of steps until the graph is connected

Tags: probability, graph-theory, expected-value

Suppose there is a graph G having N nodes (labeled 1 through N).

Initially, all of them are disconnected.

In one step, we can add an undirected edge between any two nodes i and j (1 ≤ i, j ≤ N).

We stop once the graph is one single connected component.

What is the expected number of steps to do so?

Comment: Duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126951/expected-value-of-number-of-edges-of-a-connected-graph?rq=1
but even there, there's no definitive answer

Comment: At each step is the selection of two nodes to join with an edge chosen uniformly at random?  And can the same pair of nodes get more than one edge joining them?

Comment: Yes the same pair can be taken again and again. And they are chosen uniformly at random

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asymptotically $\frac{n}{2}\log n$ steps. See Theorem 4.1 in this book about Random Graphs: [https://www.math.cmu.edu/~af1p/BOOK.pdf](https://www.math.cmu.edu/%7Eaf1p/BOOK.pdf)
You are referring to what is called the "random graph process." It is very well studied and that book contains many facts about it.